# Help understand 'where' in the sentence

Tags: grammar

> Third-generation managers take a significant step forward. They clarify their values and set goals. They plan each day and prioritize their activities.

> As I have said, ***this is where most of the time management field is today***. But this third generation has some critical limitations. ...

> The 7 Habits of Highly Effective People

I don't quite get the meaning/grammar of the sentence, especially the use of 'where'.

Can anyone help to explain the meaning and grammar of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three sentences that come first describe the practices of third generation managers. All the content of those three sentences is summarized in the word **this**.

To say that "**this is where** most of the time management field is today" means that those three sentences sum up the current situation in that field.

[American Heritage Dictionary *where*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=where)

b. At, to, or in a situation in which: *I want to know **where** you expect the project to be in six months.*

Comment: Can we read the sentence as "this is /where most of the time management field is/ today"? Then the meaning seems changed.

Comment: Yes, that's what it means. Where most of the time management field is today is here (in **this** situation).